# Firebase query where the key/value pair im looking for sits under an unknown ref

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the Firebase ref structure that i want to query:

```
- someData
    -KgWw4iasffsD-vht3QA   <=== Firebase generated key
        - fieldA: '12345'
        - fieldB: 'here it is'
```

I want to query, key eg. fieldB, and test its value. eg. fieldB = 'there it was'

Here's what i tried but ive got syntax wrong:

```
var theRef = firebase.database().ref('someData').equalTo({fieldB: 'there it was'});
```

How can i do this ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`orderByChild`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild) and [`equalTo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#equalTo) to create a query ref:

```js
var theRef = firebase.database()
  .ref('someData')
  .orderByChild('fieldB')
  .equalTo('there it was');
```

Note that you will need to [create an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) using the Firebase Security Rules. Otherwise, all of the data under `someData` will be retrieved and the query will be performed on the client.

To perform the query once, you would do something like this:

```js
theRef.once('value',
  function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
      console.log(child.key, child.val());
    });
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Or, using the returned Promise:

```js
theRef.once('value')
  .then(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
      console.log(child.key, child.val());
    });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Or, to query the data and continue listening for changes, you would do something like this:

```js
theRef.on('value',
  function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (child) {
      console.log(child.key, child.val());
    });
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Please always include a sample listener in query answers. Otherwise the next question will be: why aren't my results orders. So: `query.on('value', function(snapshot) { snapshot.forEach(function(child) { console.log(child.key); }); })` or `query.on('child_added', function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.key); })`